# File for xi:include does not exist because parser is looking from project root

Tags: java, xml

I currently have an xml resource file that has XML inclusions.

`stream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("resource/Resource.xml");`

within the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">   
    <element />
    <xi:include href="resource/1.xml"/>
</semantics>
```

However, after parsing `Resource.xml`, I get an error that the file being included does not exist.

After checking, it seems that the path was concatenated with the root directory of my project, however my problem is that the resource file `1.xml` will be inside a jar file later on.

Is it possible to make the `DocumentBuilder` to load inclusion as a reasource as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a custom `EnitityResolver2` on your `DocumentBuilder` so that you can return the correct `InputSource` when then `xi:include` is processed.

```
final DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
documentBuilder.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver2() {
    @Override
    public InputSource getExternalSubset(String string, String string1) throws SAXException, IOException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public InputSource resolveEntity(String string, String string1, String string2, String string3) throws SAXException, IOException {
        final String resourceName = string3;
        final InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setSystemId(resourceName);
        is.setByteStream(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourceName));
        return is;
    }


    @Override
    public InputSource resolveEntity(String string, String string1) throws SAXException, IOException {
        return null;
    }
});
```

This will now return an `InputSource` of the `InputStream` of the resource as loaded by the classloader. You may need to manipulate the `String` to get the right path.

Comment: I'm encountering a NullPointerException whenever calling parse. I'm certain that I'm getting a valid InputStream. Any idea how to resolve this? `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xinclude.XIncludeHandler.searchForRecursiveIncludes(Unknown Source)`

Comment: It seems, I had to set the systemId to the InputSource object. Thanks for your help. It worked.